# How to add autocomplate data from a source folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

This is simply code of jqueryui auto complete.

```
        <script>
          $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
              "ActionScript",
              "AppleScript",
              "Asp",
              "BASIC",
              "C",
              "C++",
              "Clojure",
              "COBOL",
              "ColdFusion",
              "Erlang",
              "Fortran",
              "Groovy",
              "Haskell",
              "Java",
              "JavaScript",
              "Lisp",
              "Perl",
              "PHP",
              "Python",
              "Ruby",
              "Scala",
              "Scheme"
            ];
            function split( val ) {
              return val.split( /,\s*/ );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
              return split( term ).pop();
            }

            $( "#tags" )
              // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
              .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                }
              })
              .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                  response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                },
                focus: function() {
                  // prevent value inserted on focus
                  return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                  var terms = split( this.value );
                  // remove the current input
                  terms.pop();
                  // add the selected item
                  terms.push( ui.item.value );
                  // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                  terms.push( "" );
                  this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                  return false;
                }
              });
          });
          </script>




<div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>
```

How to add data of autocomplete from a folder?
For example i want to add images name as value of autocomplete from a folder.

```
 <script>
          $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
             //images_name
            ];
            function split( val ) {
              return val.split( /,\s*/ );
            }
            function extractLast( term ) {
              return split( term ).pop();
            }

            $( "#tags" )
              // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
              .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                }
              })
              .autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: function( request, response ) {
                  // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                  response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                },
                focus: function() {
                  // prevent value inserted on focus
                  return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                  var terms = split( this.value );
                  // remove the current input
                  terms.pop();
                  // add the selected item
                  terms.push( ui.item.value );
                  // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                  terms.push( "" );
                  this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                  return false;
                }
              });
          });
          </script>




<div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
      <input id="tags" size="50">
    </div>
```

If i use $getJSON what is the code to get files/images name as array? Is there any way to do like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>

 var available_tags=[<?php 
 foreach(glob('../image/imagefiles/*.*') as $key=>$filename){

      if($key==0)
      {echo "'".$filename."'";}
      else
      {echo ",'".$filename."'";}
 }



 ?>]


</script>
```

Comment: Not working. The output of autocomplete not showing.

Comment: change directory path and check if available_tags contains data first

Comment: I did `var availableTags = [<?php 
 foreach(glob('../image/imagefiles/*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename ;
 }
 ?>];`  to  `var availableTags = ["<?php 
 foreach(glob('../image/imagefiles/*.*') as $filename){
     echo $filename ;
 }
 ?>",];` but it show me values in same/single line..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still not working need output `" ",` but your output `' ", '`

Comment: I realised my mistake... have updated the answer... check again for last time :)